# keyboard doesn't work properly in eclipse ide in ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I don't know why my juno (eclipse 4.2) IDE started behaving very wierd. Pressing delete button in file2 deletes content in file1. I tried to restore all the settings and key bindings but still it behaves the same. Please help me if someone had this issue and resolved it.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2046m
-XX:-UseParallelGC 
-XX:+AggressiveOpts 
-XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
```

adding errors from log file :

```
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+SHIFT+D R:
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+D R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.rap.ui.launch.RAPLaunchShortcut.debug,Debug RAP Application,
        Debug RAP Application,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.MakeHandlersGo@655538e5,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+D R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.wst.server.launchShortcut.debug,Debug on Server,
        Debug the current selection on a server,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.MakeHandlersGo@3e0a765c,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-08-27 09:51:34.156
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+SHIFT+X R:
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+X R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.rap.ui.launch.RAPLaunchShortcut.run,Run RAP Application,
        Run RAP Application,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.MakeHandlersGo@20e0b1d6,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(ALT+SHIFT+X R,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.wst.server.launchShortcut.run,Run on Server,
        Run the current selection on a server,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.MakeHandlersGo@7fbb6976,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
```

Comment: are you facing this problem with freshly installed eclipse, with the new workspace as well?

Comment: I tried on the new workspace today and it works fine. but with my current project workspace it behaves very wierd sometimes it does say file does not exist and keyboard doesn't work properly..don't know where the error is.

Comment: edited and added errors from log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I have no clue how to fix that, but I would not loose the time with this type of problems and:

- create the new workspace
- install plugins of your preference
- import existing projects/recreate them

I think there are real challenges out there, and your time is worth to use reasonably.

Otherwise you might get stuck in the irritating behavior of the non-usable IDE

For me, the most of the time, when I'm too much in the trouble noone else is facing this method (possibly as the last option) works :)

Comment: Thank you Peter for the help. I will follow your suggestion.